# How to replace a value with NA based on two conditions in r dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to replace a numerical value with NA based on conditions on two other columns.

This is my reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

data1 <- read.csv(text = "
  site,day,biomass,aereal,root,ei.obs
  siteA,50,464.65,2020.3,307.3,0.84
  siteA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
  siteA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
  siteA,59,1222.565,2159.5,148.3,0.93
  siteA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
  siteA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
  siteA,66,1250.86,2046.8,159.1,0.92
  siteB,50,464.65,2020.3,307.3,0.84
  siteB,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
  siteB,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
  siteB,59,1222.565,2159.5,148.3,0.93
  siteB,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
  siteB,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
  siteB,66,1250.86,2046.8,159.1,0.92")


data1.1 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(ei.obs =  if_else(site == "siteA" & day == 66, NA , ei.obs))
```

And this is the error I got:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `ei.obs`.
x `false` must be a logical vector, not a double vector.
i Input `ei.obs` is `if_else(site == "siteA" & day == 66, NA, ei.obs)`.
```

Alternatively, I tried this:

```
data1.1 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(ei.obs =  na_if(ei.obs, site == "siteA" & day == 66))
```

But nothing changes in the dataframe.

The expected outcome is this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution is to use `ifelse` instead of `if_else` :

```
library(dplyr)
data1.1 <- data1 %>% mutate(ei.obs =  ifelse(site == "siteA" & day == 66, NA , ei.obs))
```

`if_else` requires both the output of same type. `NA` is of class logical so you get the error, you can use `NA_real` instead.

```
library(dplyr)
data1.1 <- data1 %>% mutate(ei.obs =  if_else(site == "siteA" & day == 66, NA_real_, ei.obs))
```

By the way, copying your data creates whitespace in `site` column, you can remove it by using `trimws`.

```
data1$site <- trimws(data1$site)
```